Casting a value from one fintype to another?
Being a Coq newbie, I am stuck on this problem. Hopefully, someone can help!
Given an encoding of finite types in Coq as below -
Fixpoint fin (n : nat) : Type :=
  match n with
  | 0 => False
  | S m => option (fin m)
  end.

Is it possible to define a function that lifts a value from fin (S n) to fin (S (S n)), while keeping the value the same. Thus, I am hoping to have the following equalities such as -
@up 2 (None : fin 2) = (None : fin 3)
@up 2 (Some None : fin 2) = (Some None : fin 3)
I thought of writing this -
Fixpoint up {n:nat} : fin (S n) -> fin (S (S n)) :=
fun p => match p with 
         | None => None 
         | Some p' => Some (up p)

But it is rejected. Intuitively I understand that it is possible because - members of fin 2 - None, Some None are members of fin 3 - None, Some None, Some (Some None) and so on. But I am not able to write the function for the same. I suspect its because the recursive definition has to deal with @up 0 where there should be an empty match, but I am not sure how to write this case. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

You will need dependent pattern matching for your term to type-check properly.
Your structural parameter can only be n because this is the sole parameter of your Fixpoint. Your recursive call must be applied on a sub-term of n so you need a match on n somewhere.
I would favor the solution below, of return type fin n -> fin (S n), which is a bit more general, but you can specialize it to fin (S n) -> fin (S (S n)) later on of needed:
Fixpoint up {n} : fin n -> fin (S n) :=
  match n return fin n -> fin (S n) with 
  | 0   => fun p => match p with end
  | S n => fun p => match p with 
                    | None => None
                    | Some q => Some (up q)
                    end
  end.

Goal forall n, @up (S n) None = None.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

Goal forall n (p : fin n), @up (S n) (Some p) = Some (up p).
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

Fixpoint fin2nat {n} : fin n -> nat :=
  match n with 
  | 0   => fun p => match p with end
  | S n => fun p => match p with
                    | None   => 0
                    | Some p => S (fin2nat p)
                    end
  end.

Eval compute in @fin2nat 8 (Some (Some (Some None))).
Eval compute in @fin2nat 20 (Some (Some (Some None))).

Fact up_correct {n} p : fin2nat (@up n p) = fin2nat p.
Proof.
  induction n as [ | n IHn ] in p |- *; destruct p; simpl fin2nat; trivial.
  f_equal; exact (IHn _).
Qed. 


Perfect! Thank you. This works.
If you could answer one last question I had, I tried writing this -
Fixpoint up2 {n} (m : fin n) : fin (S n) :=   match n return fin (S n) with   | 0 => match m with end   | S n => match m with None => None | Some q => Some (up q) end   end.
But this does not type-check - Found a matching with no clauses on a term unknown to have an empty inductive type.
Could you tell me what's different? As far as I can seem, in your version you have matched on the function type, whereas here I am matching on the argument.

Well when you do a pattern matching on a hypothesis, only the return type can depend on the value of that argument. Especially, not the types of the other hypotheses. If you want to do when m being also a parameter of up2, this is how to proceed: Fixpoint up2 {n} (m : fin n) : fin (S n) := match n return fin n -> fin (S n) with | 0 => fun m => match m with end | S n => fun m => match m with | None => None | Some q => Some (up2 q) end end m.

Ah okay. That makes sense, Thank you so much!

A useful way to debug is to go to replace your definition by its proof mode counterpart to see what is happening:
Fixpoint up {n:nat} : fin (S n) -> fin (S (S n)).
cbn in *. intro p; destruct p as [p' |].
- (* case Some *)
- (* case None *)

if you do, you'll see that you are trying to build a term of type option (option (fin n)) knowing:
up: forall n : nat,
     option (fin n) ->
     option (option (fin n))
n: nat
p': fin n
--------------------------------
option (option (fin n))

so obviously up p does not type check
But actually you are thinking too much, here there is no need for induction as fin (S n) is option n so you can just define up {n} : fin n -> fin (S n) as Some:
Definition up {n:nat} : fin n -> fin (S n) := Some.


Thank you for the response. I think I wasn't clear in the question. I would like to view a value of fin n as the same values in fin (S n). So, for example applying up to None : fin 2 should give None : fin 3. I will edit the question, to reflect the same.
